# How Angular application work when I enter URL directly in browser?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I know Angular work by something called Single-Page-Application.
But what puzzled me is that when I enter URL directly in the browser. It can still find the correctly page.

For example. When I enter `http://localhost/`, I know it is going to the display `index.html`
But when I enter `http://localhost/asd`, It can still work, but the build result didn't contain `asd`.
How??? Dear SO community.

Comment: The Angular Documentation is pretty good, I would check out the information on the Router https://angular.io/guide/routing-overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turn out I config my go server to direct all 404 page to the `index.html` so that when I input `http://localhost/asd` in navigation bar, it direct to `index.html`, and `/asd` is then processed by single page application of angular with `windows.location.url`

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain.

1. Server starts by serving the index.html.
2. If you check contents of the index.html you will find

app-root or a similar selector that will decide which component will be loaded.

3. app-root is the selector of app.component.ts

Meaning it will display app.component by default.

4. Note that this is the default case. http://localhost/asd and others all default to this.

You can see how to default to a diffent component by default on this stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/my-angular-starter-g2kuyy?file=index.html

Note: If you want to have different sets of navigation, you can achieve that by routing.

Comment: My question is, event if I write a route `asd` in angular application. And then build it, the output files are not contain `asd.html`. So why is that when I type `localhost/asd` directly in browser, it can still locate asd's component content? 
I know your point, but doesn't that mean you have to firstly open `index.html`?
Even if I open a empty tab and type in `localhost/asd` it still perform ok

Answer (score 0):

The server is probably configured to respond with the HTML document that bootstraps the Angular application for any URL that would normally throw a 404 error.

Comment: I use Golang with GIN-Framework. And just using `gin.Default()`

Answer (score 0):

How ?

In any case if you access an url like `http://my-url.com` or `http://localhost/` and you pass whatever after the `/` it will work unless you made a redirection to 404 page or wherever you'd like.

Why ?

Because your url is correct, and doesn't handle what you pass as a parameter of your url, unless you make it handle it.

Comment: No, I mean. I build a angular app to a folder called `dist`. But in this folder I can only find `index.html` and other non-html files. But when I deploy this `dist` folder into a running web-server. and enter `localhost/asd`, It can still locate the right content that I placed in angular app. How so?